# Python id of name and '__main__' different

Tags: python

Normally if I assign a variable some value, and then check their ids, I expect them to be the same, because python is essentially just giving my object a "name". This can be seen in the below code:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> id(a)
19845928
>>> id(3)
19845928
```

The problem is when I perform the same with "**name**"

```
>>> __name__
'__main__'
>>> id(__name__)
19652416
>>> id('__main__')
19652448
```

How can there ids be different, shouldn't they be the same? Because `__name__` should also be just a reference.

Comment: `(id("__main__") == id(__name__)) == True`

Comment: then why is it showing different on idle??

Comment: @JakobBowyer: your comment evaluates as False on my Cpython (and pypy), so don't blame IDLE.

Comment: @JakobBowyer: That's not true. Don't confuse the guy. The reason is that while equal-value strings may have the same memory pointer, they are not guaranteed to. The exact behavior is undefined.

Comment: This is why the idiom is `__name__ == '__main__'`. Check for logical (string) equality, not object identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

id() gives essentially the memory pointer to the data. Although strings are immutable, they are not guaranteed to be interned. This means that some strings with equal values have different pointers.

For integers (especially small ones), the pointers will be the same, so your `3` example works fine.

---

@KartikAnand: The way you're checking for 'same object' is valid, although the usual way is to use `x is y`. The problem is that they are *not* the same object, and not guaranteed to be. They simply have the same value. Note that when you do `"__main__"` you're creating a new object. Sometimes python does a nice optimization and re-uses a previously-created string of the same value, but it doesn't *have* to.

---

Kartik's goal is to "verify that assignment is in a way reference and objects are not created on the fly". To do this, avoid creating new objects (no string literals).

```
>>> __name__
'__main__'
>>> x = __name__
>>> id(__name__)
3078339808L
>>> id(x)
3078339808L
>>> __name__ is x
True
```

Comment: +1 for `is` -- I was about to say the same thing. But I'm not sure about `hash` -- it's not clear that the OP is looking to hash anything.

Comment: hash() would work where id() fails, is all I'm saying. He seems to want an integer that will compare equal for equal objects.

Comment: This helps to prove that `id()` gives the memory address (pointer) to an object: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578132/

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: Please note that this is an implementation detail of id() and is different for alternative interpreters, or possibly future versions of python.

Comment: @bukzor i just wanted to verify that assignment is in a way reference and objects are not created on the fly..i am not looking to compare anything..i was just curious why arent their ids same

Comment: @NoctisSkytower, seconding buzkor, IIRC IronPython's `id` just assigns consecutive integers to each object as it is called.

Comment: @bukzor This is what I was looking for..this cleared my doubts..thanks :)

Comment: @bukzor: The code is warned as not being reliable for that very reason.

Answer (score 4):

Just because two strings have the same value, it does not follow that they are the same object. This is completely expected behaviour.

Comment: You haven't educated the newbie. You've left out a lot of detail necessary to understand your "answer".

Comment: @bukzor What details have I left out? Which terms require further definition for you to understand this question?

Comment: Mainly, he doesn't seem to know that there are two strings.

Comment: @bukzor So...you don't see the words "two strings" in my answer?

Comment: That's not at issue, is it? As the OP, it's a reference with no antecedent. He obviously only sees one string in his example.

Comment: @bukzor Yes, and this answer explains that there are two.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say your answer is perfect.

Comment: @bukzor It's possible for my answer to be less than perfect, and your criticism to be, frankly, nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, small integers are "pooled", so that all small integer values point to the same object. This is not necessary true for strings.

At any rate, this is an implementation detail that should not be relied upon.

Comment: then how can i check that they refer to the same objects??

Comment: Normally you want to check if they are the same *value*, in which case you can just use `==`.

Comment: @KartikAnand, why do you care whether they refer to the same object?

Comment: I know i can use that, but seeing that python uses references instead of creating new objects shouldn't there be a technique to keep a check?i always thought id can help

Comment: @KartikAnand What is your actual usecase here?  As many have said, most of the time, you are looking to do value, not object comparisons.

Comment: @KartikAnand: Well, if you want to see if two variables point to the same object, then use `id()` (or the `is` operator). You just have to know that two variables may evaluate to the same *value* but point to different *objects*.

Comment: @sr2222 i was just playing with idle when this struck me..yesterday i saw how pure assignment can be dangerous due to references being involved...so i was checking it it holds for every python object.

Comment: @mipadi you are saying if i want to check if two variables point to the same object use id() and then you're also saying i cant rely on id()..isn't that vague?

Comment: @wooble If I assign variables to each other then it can be dangerous right?Because now both of them point to the same object.That's what I want to check..

Comment: @KartikAnand In what sense is having two variables referring to the same object dangerous?

Comment: @KartikAnand, no it's not vague. Identity and value are _two different things_. Two different objects can have the same value. An object can have two different values (at different times, if it is mutable).

Comment: @KartikAnand: It's reliable to use `id()` or `is` to see if two variables point to the same object, but it's not a reliable test for value equality.

Comment: @Marcin dangerous for me because I'm not used to it :)

Comment: @mipadi, This is inaccurate.  `for x in range(10): for y in range(10): if x!=y: print x is y` will show you that the ids for small integers are not the same.

Comment: @KartikAnand What are you used to? I'm not aware of any programming language that always copies the underlying object on assignment.

Comment: @marcin I was getting confused with lists,where references were being copied

Comment: @sr2222: Well, obviously, if x != y, they're not pointing to the same object. Try `for x in xrange(1): for y in xrange(10): print x, y, x is y`. Or even simpler: `x = 1; y = 1; x is y`. (Regardless, it's an implementation detail anyway.)

Comment: @mipadi But that's not what you said.  You said, "all small integer values point to the same object."  My code (and your later statements) show they do not.  Maybe what you meant to say was, "for integers with small values, all references to integers of the same value point to the same instance."

Answer (score 0):

What you are running in to here is the fact that primitives are pseudo (or real) singletons in Python.  Further, looking at strings clouds the issue because when strings are interned, value and id become synonymous as a side effect, so some strings with value matches will have id matches and others won't.  Try looking at hand-built objects instead, as then you control when  a new instance is created, and id vs value becomes more explicitly clear.