# Does repeated identical assignment going to lead to the same id() value?

Tags: python, object, variable-assignment

This question is motivated by this 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10639226/1209279) which I both misread and
provided a botched answer (I deleted it)

I re-read http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id and just tried this in Python:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> id(a)
5392456

>>> a = 3
>>> id(a)
5392456
```

repeated a few times more ...

The fact that these numbers (ie addresses of the object in memory) are
the same is implementation dependent, and ***not*** guaranteed, is that
correct? They could be different, right? My understanding is that each time I do
this simple assignment, I am creating a new object and binding it to a variable
identifier, so I *can't* assume that they would be put in the same place
in memory.

Is this understanding correct? If so, are there any exceptions?

Comment: An implementation is free to never intern anything.

Comment: @interjay ok, so you are confirming that my understanding of this is correct, right? And the fact that my example gave the same memory value was not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't count on it being the same. Situations in which `id` is useful are very rare.

Comment: Not sure why I got the downvote over a month after the post ... I thought the question was clear and I did some footwork of my own too .. go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make that assumption but a times for immutable types like `int` rather than create a new object, your variable might just reference the immutable object if it already exist. When you do an assignment you are creating a reference to an object. That object might be already around or might be created.

Comment: so I can't ever **assume**  about the value being the same, right? (That's at least what I wanted to confirm with my question)

Comment: if you assign a value say 3 to a variable `a`, the variable references an `int` object of value 3. You can have more than one object with same value but different object `id`. What you care about is that when you use the variable `a` you have a value of 3 so how the python VM deals with the object depends on the implementation and you should **never** count on them being the same.